# Archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, installation, update

Trying to update a 2.5.16 site to 2.5.28 then to 3.4.1 however when I follow the official guide [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration) I see the following error message popup on screen when clicking 'write files directly'.

> The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing

I ftpd into my site and noticed that I had no `/tmp` folder (no idea why), so I created (755 permissions) one and re-tried however the error persists. I have cleared cache, purges cache, logged in/out also.

**Update**

It's definitley an issue with the remote host (1and1) because I am able to copy the site to my local XAMPP setup and upgrade with no issues.

Looks like my `/tmp` and `/log` paths weren't set correctly (I wasn't using the hosts absolute root path). Having set this and tried to to 3.4.1 via the extension manager, it stopps at 26% and gives the fowwowing error;

> unable to open index.html for writing

Accessing the homepage (blank) I am receiving;

> Fatal error: JControllerBase cannot implement JController - it is not
>   an interface in myDomain/htdocs/libraries/joomla/controller/base.php
>   on line 18

Most likely issues with the `/log` folder as described [here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/site-restoration/12473-problems-with-1a1.html) although I will post back (when I've tried @Lodders suggestion!).

Comment: Is your Temp Path in the Global Configuration set correctly?

Comment: Cool. Yes, this can sometimes be the issue. The tmp directory is required as it stores a copy of the extension zip for Joomla to then extract and move the files to the appropriate directories, therefore not having it defined correctly means Joomla can't process the zip file you're uploading.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Have you checked that all folders/files are writable in Joomla System Information section in the backend? May I also suggest that you check with your hosting provider that there no hidden folder called `logs` that's conflicting with Joomla's `logs` directory.

Comment: Ahh ok. In which case, rename your Joomla `logs` directory to `logs2` and then make sure you also define that in the Global Configuration. Then try the upgrade again ;)

Comment: Thanks @Lodder I'm going to try this now and I'll report back, I think you're correct though. I've also updated my question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your first question regarding the issue with the temp directory:**

Yes, this can sometimes be the issue. The tmp directory is required as it stores a copy of the extension zip for Joomla to then extract and move the files to the appropriate directories, therefore not having it defined correctly means Joomla can't process the zip file you're uploading.

**As for the log directory:**

This directory is used to store log files that are created with Joomla [JLog](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLog.html) class. If this is not set correctly, you will get the following message as shown in your question:

> could not open log for writing

Answer (score 2):

Hoping this helps someone; my path to tmp was correctly set within Joomla so to solve this problem I accessed the /tmp folder via FTP client and deleted the existing .zip update file that was in there. I then ran the update again and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Many thanks for this tip. Sorted my issue :)